# How to filter multiple rows based on rows and columns condition in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to filter multiple rows based on "value" column. Ex, i want filter `velocity` from `channel_name` column where `value>=1 & value <=5` and  i want filter `Temp` from `channel_name` column where `value>=0 & value <=2`. Below id my Pysaprk DF.

| start_timestamp | channel_name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-02 08:51:50 | velocity | 1 |
| 2020-11-02 09:14:29 | Temp | 0 |
| 2020-11-02 09:18:32 | velocity | 0 |
| 2020-11-02 09:32:42 | velocity | 4 |
| 2020-11-03 13:06:03 | Temp | 2 |
| 2020-11-03 13:10:01 | Temp | 1 |
| 2020-11-03 13:54:38 | Temp | 5 |
| 2020-11-03 14:46:25 | velocity | 5 |
| 2020-11-03 14:57:31 | Kilometer | 6 |
| 2020-11-03 15:07:07 | Kilometer | 7 |

Expected DF:

| start_timestamp | channel_name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-11-02 08:51:50 | velocity | 1 |
| 2020-11-02 09:32:42 | velocity | 4 |
| 2020-11-03 14:46:25 | velocity | 5 |
| 2020-11-02 09:14:29 | Temp | 0 |
| 2020-11-03 13:06:03 | Temp | 2 |
| 2020-11-03 13:10:01 | Temp | 1 |

I tried for channel_name `Velocity` and it is working fine.

```
df1=df.filter((df.channel_name ==  "velocity") & (df.interpreted_value >= 1 )  & (df.interpreted_value <= 5))
```

but i dont know how i can do this for multiple `channel_name` like `Velocity` and `Temp` :below is code, also let me know if this is right way to do or how i can do that.

```
df1=df.filter(((df.channel_name ==  "velocity") & (df.interpreted_value >= 1 )  & 
                  (df.interpreted_value <= 5))) &
              ((df.channel_name ==  "Temp") & (df.interpreted_value >= 0 )  & 
                  (df.interpreted_value <= 2))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an *or* (`|`) instead of an *and*(`&`) operator when you combine the clauses:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("2020-11-02 08:51:50", "velocity", 1),
  ("2020-11-02 09:14:29", "Temp", 0),
  ("2020-11-02 09:18:32", "velocity", 0),
  ("2020-11-02 09:32:42", "velocity", 4),
  ("2020-11-03 13:06:03", "Temp", 2),
  ("2020-11-03 13:10:01", "Temp", 1),
  ("2020-11-03 13:54:38", "Temp", 5),
  ("2020-11-03 14:46:25", "velocity", 5),
  ("2020-11-03 14:57:31", "Kilometer",6),
  ("2020-11-03 15:07:07", "Kilometer", 7)], 
  ["start_timestamp", "channel_name", "value"]).withColumn("start_timestamp", F.to_timestamp("start_timestamp"))

df_filtered = df.filter((((df.channel_name ==  "velocity") & (df.value >= 1 )  & 
                  (df.value <= 5))) | # or instead of and
              ((df.channel_name ==  "Temp") & (df.value >= 0 )  & 
                  (df.value <= 2)))
df_filtered.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------------------+------------+-----+
|    start_timestamp|channel_name|value|
+-------------------+------------+-----+
|2020-11-02 08:51:50|    velocity|    1|
|2020-11-02 09:14:29|        Temp|    0|
|2020-11-02 09:32:42|    velocity|    4|
|2020-11-03 13:06:03|        Temp|    2|
|2020-11-03 13:10:01|        Temp|    1|
|2020-11-03 14:46:25|    velocity|    5|
+-------------------+------------+-----+
```

The filter you currently apply will return nothing, since you first check if channel name is equal to one specific string and then afterwards check if it is equal to another specific string. With or, only one of the clauses should be true to include the row in in the result dataframe.

Comment: thanks that worked well. still logically confused AND should work right insted of OR ?
As i want both bracket conditions to be true.

Comment: You want to keep each row where either of the brackets return true. You can never have both of the brackets return true, because the two string comparisons will never be true at the same time.